# R mapbox / plotly with animation and a shapefile

Tags: r, animation, plotly, mapbox

I'm putting together an animation that shows spatial data plotted on a map, with a date-based animation slider. In addition to these, I want to plot a shapefile that is stationary over time.
My animation works fine without the shapefile. Plotting both markers and shapefile doesn't show the shapefile (seems to be some kind of a disconnect between `add_sf` and the `layout` specs that I don't understand), and also breaks the animation. How can these be made to work together? I think I need to stick with the `plot_ly` specification (as opposed to `plot_mapbox`) to make other components of my actual plot work together ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145055/r-plotly-display-image-on-hover-in-a-map/77145696?noredirect=1#comment136069467_77145696) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906457/plotly-map-and-plot-with-shared-animation)).

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
      select(AREA) %>%
       sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
       sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-76, -84, -2), y = seq(34, 36, 1),
                  Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-04-01"), by = "1 day")) %>%
      mutate(x = rnorm(n(), x, 1),
              y = rnorm(n(), y, 1),
             Date = as.factor(Date))


df %>%
  plot_ly(lon = ~x, lat = ~y, frame = ~Date, 
          type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers") %>%
  ######### this line breaks the animation and doesn't show the sf. Uncomment to check
  #########add_sf(data = nc, inherit = FALSE, color = I("white")) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                     center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                     layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                        source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add-On**

To change the order of the traces 2 things have to happen, the literal trace order and the trace index assigned to each frame. Everything in my original answer still applies, but in lieu of `fixer()`, here is `fixer2()`

```
fixer2 <- function(plt1, plt2) {
  # change the order of the traces (considering fixer())
  # where plt1 has frames and plt2 does not
  # get lines' trace from plt2, add to plt1 as the first trace
  # change the 'trace' index in each frame in plt1$x$frames
  plt1 <- plotly_build(plt1); plt2 <- plotly_build(plt2)  # prep by building
  lines2 <- lapply(1:length(plt2$x$data), function(i) {
    if(plt2$x$data[[i]]$mode == "lines") {   # extract index for combined plot
      return(i)
    }
  }) %>% unlist()
  plt1$x$data <- append(plt2$x$data[lines2], plt1$x$data) # add data diff order
  lapply(1:length(plt1$x$frames), function(j) {    # change frames trace index
    plt1$x$frames[[j]]$traces <<- 1 + plt1$x$frames[[j]]$traces
  }) # this assumes scatter is one color
  plt1   # return modified plot
}
fixer2(p1, p2)
```

##### The Original Answer (before the add-on)

I'm guessing that what you're looking for is a static outline of NC's counties during the animation. If that's an accurate assumption this will work. I tried several different approaches because I don't understand why Plotly gets so lost in translation. However, I could only get it to function appropriately with a workaround (versus a plotly parameter or something along those lines).

First, I'll show you my solution.

Then I've got a *did you know?* and a *perhaps this would look a bit better if...*

##### The plot

I created two `scattermapbox` plots and combined them with a UDF. I've essentially used your code, but made both `scattermapbox` (versus one `scattermapbox` and one `add_sf`).

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  select(AREA) %>%
  sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
  sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")

df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-76, -84, -2), y = seq(34, 36, 1),
                  Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-04-01"), by = "1 day")) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(n(), x, 1),
         y = rnorm(n(), y, 1),
         Date = as.factor(Date))


p1 <- plot_ly(data = df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, frame = ~Date, 
              type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers") %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) 

p2 <- plot_ly(data = nc, type = "scattermapbox", color = I("white")) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}")))))
```

In the UDF, I take the `lines` trace from the `data = nc` plot and add that data to the other plot.

```
fixer <- function(plt1, plt2) {
  # where plt1 has frames and plt2 does not
  # get lines' trace from plt2
  # add lines' trace data to plt1$x$data 
  plt1 <- plotly_build(plt1); plt2 <- plotly_build(plt2)  # prep by building
  lines2 <- lapply(1:length(plt2$x$data), function(i) {
    if(plt2$x$data[[i]]$mode == "lines") {   # extract index for combined plot
      return(i)
    }
  }) %>% unlist()
  plt1$x$data <- append(plt1$x$data, plt2$x$data[lines2]) # add data to plt1
  plt1   # return modified plot
}
fixer(p1, p2)
```

[image]

[image]

##### Did you know?

You did some extra work with the `nc` data, using `select` and `st_cast`. However, that work didn't change anything...I'm not sure what the objective was there.

To create an identical map, you can leave the data as-is and add `fill = "none"` to the trace.

Here's a visual explanation.

```
nc2 <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

p3 <- plot_ly(data = nc2, fill = "none", type = "scattermapbox", color = I("white")) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) 
fixer(p1, p3)
```

[image]

##### It might look a bit better if...

I noticed that the lines are so thick, that it's difficult to see the animation, so I thought I would add in that the default line in `scattermapbox` is `line = list(width = 2)`. In this variation, I used the original `nc` data and cut the line width in half. (It's still really ostentatious though.)

```
p4 <- plot_ly(data = nc2, fill = "none", type = "scattermapbox", color = I("white"), 
              line = list(width = 1)) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) 
fixer(p1, p4)
```

[image]

##### All the code altogether

Here's all the code (broken down above) in one place (easier copy + paste and all that).

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  select(AREA) %>%
  sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
  sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")

df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-76, -84, -2), y = seq(34, 36, 1),
                  Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-04-01"), by = "1 day")) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(n(), x, 1),
         y = rnorm(n(), y, 1),
         Date = as.factor(Date))

#---------------------------- basic fix ----------------------------
p1 <- plot_ly(data = df, lon = ~x, lat = ~y, frame = ~Date, 
              type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers") %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) 

p2 <- plot_ly(data = nc, type = "scattermapbox", color = I("white")) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) 


fixer <- function(plt1, plt2) {
  # where plt1 has frames and plt2 does not
  # get lines' trace from plt2
  # add lines' trace data to plt1$x$data 
  plt1 <- plotly_build(plt1); plt2 <- plotly_build(plt2)  # prep by building
  lines2 <- lapply(1:length(plt2$x$data), function(i) {
    if(plt2$x$data[[i]]$mode == "lines") {   # extract index for combined plot
      return(i)
    }
  }) %>% unlist()
  plt1$x$data <- append(plt1$x$data, plt2$x$data[lines2]) # add data to plt1
  plt1   # return modified plot
}
fixer(p1, p2)


#---------------------- using NC data as is-------------------------
nc2 <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

p3 <- plot_ly(data = nc2, fill = "none", type = "scattermapbox", color = I("white")) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) 
fixer(p1, p3)

#----------- basic NC data & different line aesthetics -------------
p4 <- plot_ly(data = nc2, fill = "none", type = "scattermapbox", color = I("white"), 
              line = list(width = 1)) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(style = "white-bg", sourcetype = 'raster', zoom = 4,
                       center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35),
                       layers = list(list(below = 'traces', sourcetype = "raster",
                                          source = list("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"))))) 
fixer(p1, p4)
```

Comment: You're incredible. Is there a way to put the boundaries under the points? I tried swapping the append arguments, but that was obviously not the right way about it, based on the results, lol. Also - you have no idea how comforting it is to see "I don't understand why" from you, given that I've been trying to resolve this for a long time now.

Comment: Changing the trace order equates to which trace is on top. I've added `fixer2()` to my answer (at the top). This changes the trace order. If you had more than one trace in each frame (which generally happens when there is more than 1 discrete color or the argument `split` is used) you would have to add 1 to each index in `plt1$x$frames[[?]]$trace` instead of just adding 1 in general, as I did in `fixer2()`. If that doesn't make sense, let me know.

Comment: Amazing. I'll be working in the next few days on putting together all the individual bits you've helped me with. Hopefully the multiple flavours of the `fixer` function you've put together for me can coexist together (or else there might be more questions...) If I'm ever in Chicagoland, I definitely owe you a beer!