# R plotly scattermapbox animation breaks when setting animation_opts

Tags: r, plotly, mapbox

My R plot_ly animation that shows markers on a basemap for different years stops working when I adapt the animation options (frame and transition time) with animation_opts(). The line seems to change the way the traces/frames are read by plotly; except from frame 1 (year 2011), also the hoverinfo is broken for the other frames. My knowledge of the underlying workings of plotly are too limited to get behind this seemingly simple issue.

Here some example code (please ignore the misplacement of markers in relation to the basemap):

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(plotly)

set.seed(8)

df <- expand.grid(lon = seq(16.38964, 16.44847, 0.03), lat = seq(48.18159, 48.21667, 0.03),
                  jahr_fertigstellung = seq(2011, 2023, by = 1),
                  ANZWO = seq(1, 8, by = 1)) %>%
  mutate(lon = rnorm(n(), lon, 1),
         lat = rnorm(n(), lat, 1),
         ANZWO = as.factor(ANZWO),
         labels = glue::glue('Jahr Fertigstellung: {jahr_fertigstellung}, \nAnzahl Wohnungen: {ANZWO}'))

#create viridis palette for 8 factor groups / numeric range
cols <- viridis(8, direction = -1, option = "D")

plotly.map <- df %>%
  plot_ly(lon = ~lon,
          lat = ~lat,
          frame = ~jahr_fertigstellung,
          size = 20,
          color = ~ANZWO,
          colors = ~cols,
          opacity = 1,
          #fill = ~'',
          text = ~labels,
          hoverinfo = "text",
          type  = 'scattermapbox',
          mode  = 'markers',
          showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(mapbox= list(
    style = "white-bg",
    zoom = 6,
    center = list(lon = 16.372504 ,lat= 48.208354),
    layers = list(list(
      below = 'traces',
      sourcetype = "raster",
      source = list("https://mapsneu.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmapgrau/normal/google3857/{z}/{y}/{x}.png"))))) %>%
# This line breaks animation + hoverinfo (uncomment it to test the working animation)
  animation_opts(frame = 1500, transition = 0, redraw = FALSE) %>% # Slower animation + no transition / redraw
  animation_slider(
    currentvalue = list(prefix = "Jahr Fertigstellung: ", font = list(color="red"))
  )

plotly.map
```

A similar issue was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76909502/r-mapbox-plotly-with-animation-and-a-shapefile) but does not relate to the animation_opts argument. I inspected the plotly.js for both the working and broken plotlys and there seems no real difference in both. Number of frames and data is the same, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the 'redraw' argument in animation_opts(). If it is set to `redraw = TRUE` , everything works fine.